# Timing a Python program using time.clock() vs. time.time()

Tags: python, python-3.x, benchmarking

I am new to Python programming. I started working on Project Euler this morning and I wanted to find out how long it takes to execute my solution. I have searched online for a solution to my

```
import time

class Solution(object):
    def fibonacci(self,limit):
        sum = 0
        current = 1
        next = 2
        while(current <= limit):
            if  current % 2==0:
                sum += current
            current, next = next, current + next

        return  str(sum)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.clock()
    solution = Solution().fibonacci(4000000)
    elapsed = time.clock()-start
    print("Solution: %s"%(solution))
    print("Time: %s seconds"%(elapsed))
```

---

Output:
Solution: 4613732
Time: 2.006085436846098e-05 seconds

---

```
import time

class Solution(object):
    def fibonacci(self,limit):
        sum = 0
        current = 1
        next = 2
        while(current <= limit):
            if  current % 2==0:
                sum += current
            current, next = next, current + next

        return  str(sum)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    solution = Solution().fibonacci(4000000)
    elapsed = time.time()-start
    print("Solution: %s"%(solution))
    print("Time: %s seconds"%(elapsed))
```

---

Output:
Solution: 4613732
Time: 0.0 seconds

---

My question is

1. Is the time calculated above correct?
2. What is the difference between time.time() vs time.clock(). If I use time.time() I get 0.0 as time.

Comment: Migrated from Code Review because the question is not asking for open-ended suggestions for improvement, but rather asks for an explanation about a specific programming issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the Python [`time` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html), [`time.clock()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.clock) measures the time since the first call of the function in seconds, and [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.time) measures the time since January 1st, 1970, in seconds.

`time.clock()` is generally more precise, so using this is what I recommend. This is the reason why you have the tiny result in the first example, rounded down to zero in the second example.